# Como adaptar el icono de una app en Android Studio segun el tamaño de pantalla?

Tags: android

Terminé mi aplicación solo me falta personalizarla cambiando el icono, ya lo hice sin embargo se ve mucho mas pequeño que el de los demás, ¿a qué se debe? o ¿cómo lo corrijo?.

[image: mi imagen tiene como nombre GES tiene un tamaño de 512x 512]

Answer (score 0):

- Crear un archivo de imagen PNG de tamaño 512x512 píxeles En Android
  Studio, en la vista del proyecto, resalte un directorio mipmap
- En el menú, vaya a Archivo> Nuevo> Activo de imagen
- Haga clic en el botón Imagen en la fila del botón Tipo de activo
- Haga clic en 3 Dot Box a la derecha de Path Box.
- Arrastre la imagen al cuadro de recursos de origen
- Haga clic en Siguiente (Nota: los archivos de inicio existentes se
  sobrescribirán)
- Haga clic en Finalizar

Answer (score 0):

Se ve así por la resolución que estas usando, para solucionar esto te recomiendo hacer lo siguiente:

Irás a `File > Settings > plugins`:

En el buscador escribirás, "`Android Drawable importer`" te dirá que no está, que si deseas buscarlo en los repositorios, das clic allí, luego te aparece el `plugin`, en la parte superior derecha te saldrá un botón verde, que dice instalar:[image: plugin Android Drawable Importer]

Luego de instalarlo, te pedirá reiniciar `Android Studio`, una vez reiniciado, irás al directorio, `app > res` y sobre la carpeta `drawable` das clic derecho, `new > Batch Drawable Importer` (esta opción aparece debido al `plugin` instalado) te aparecerá esta pantalla:

[image: Batch Drawable Importer]

Das clic en el botón de `+` y te aparece tu directorio, en el cual seleccionaras la imagen que desees en este caso tu icono de `app`, lo seleccionas y te saldrá una pantalla así:

[image: Imagen seleccionada]

Luego le das `OK` y automáticamente te creara iconos de todas las densidades de pantalla:  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este caso tu icono se adaptara según necesite, luego seleccionas esta imagen en tu icono y automáticamente `Android Studio` seleccionara la imagen o en tu caso el icono del tamaño adecuado. Este `plugin` te sirve para hacer lo mismo con imágenes que necesites, ya sea para alguna función de alguna pantalla o para los iconos.

Otra forma es ir a `File > new Imagen Asset`.

Te mostrara un panel con los distintos tamaños de iconos, configuras a preferencia, acá también seleccionas el icono que deseas, das `Next` haces las ultimas configuraciones, entre estas el tamaño y dimensión y le das `finish`. Y también te genera los iconos de múltiples densidades de pantalla

Comment: hazme saber por favor si te ha funcionado, espero te sirva, saludos.